# How do I use thumbs-up emoji in Blogger's reaction feature in post layout settings?

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, blogger, emoji

I'm trying to use thumbs-up/down emojis in Blogger's reaction feature in the post layout settings instead of text, but two question marks inside black diamonds are showing up instead. I put `<meta charset='utf-8'/>` in the head and that didn't help. Looking deeper, it appears that Blogger uses an iframe with a url that includes all of the reaction options inside of brackets, so I'm not sure how to convert the emoji so it appears on the actual post as emoji characters. Here's the element via the source code.

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" class="reactions-iframe" frameborder="0" name="reactions" scrolling="no" src="https://www.blogger.com/blog-post-reactions.g?options=%5BLike,+Dislike%5D&amp;textColor=%23ffffff#https://video-contagion.blogspot.com/2017/09/the-insane-full-house-theory-that-might.html"></iframe>
```

If I change the Like and Dislike in `%5BLike,+Dislike%5D` to either the emojis themselves or their percent codes, which Blogger automatically converts the emoji to via the layout settings, I'm still getting the two question marks.

[image]

In addition, if I add the emojis' hex codes to the reactions settings in Blogger, it just shows the codes as text.

[image]

Should I be using another code to make these emojis show up?